# Designing a database for time table for a school management system

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

Hello I'm about to create a school management system where it should assure the relashionship between teachers, classes,periods, days, sections a single teacher can teach different subject in different class same subject can be taught by different teacher in different classes,etc   ...Some good ideas on the DB structure and the system will be appreciated. link for demo http://www.school.eptins.com

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's a good start. Good luck. If you'll encounter any **specific** problem on your journey don't hesitate to ask it here. Please find a few moments to read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

According to the information you have provided, You database design will be like in the image below.
[image]

Comment: Thank Muhammad Jawad ! I appreciate your help, but it did not helped me very much. Could you please visit the link i have provided, then make database table structure please !!  http://www.school.eptins.com